# Position text to start at same height

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}

\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  {\huge FIRSTNAME LASTNAME} & {Email : \href{mailto:mail@outlook.com}{mail@outlook.com}} \\
  {} & Mobile : +55 555 555 555 \\
\end{tabular*}


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

(sorry for the extra packages, not entirely sure yet what it needs to compile)
that produces the result:

[image]

How can I remove the space at the top right represented by the red arrows?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for the suggestion, changed it to a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with tabular and rows, you can adjust heights as shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
\oddsidemargin=0in
\textwidth=5.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \hline
  {\huge FIRSTNAME LASTNAME} & \raisebox{7.25pt}{Email : mail@outlook.com} \\
   & Mobile : +55 555 555 555 \\
\end{tabular*}


\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \hline
  {\huge FIRSTNAME LASTNAME} & \raisebox{7.25pt}{%
               \begin{tabular}[t]{l}Email : mail@outlook.com\\ Mobile : +55 555 555 555 \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

There are two examples there, the first just lines up the first line, and the second applies with two lines on the right.

I don't like these solutions much, because I had to fiddle with the dimension in `\raisebox{...}`.  (I had calculated that it should be 10pt, but then I had to adjust when reality was different.). But if you're just going to do it once-ish, a little fiddling might be OK.

Comment: Thank you, going with the second option!

Comment: Great! (Hit the check mark if you like)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

With table, where in the first column is used `\multirow[t]{<number of rows}`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
            }

\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Xr @{}}
\multirow[t]{3}{=}{FIRSTNAME LASTNAME}
    &   Email:  \href{mailto:mail@outlook.com}{mail@outlook.com}    \\
    &   Mobile: +55 555 555 555                                     \\
    &   some unknown text  
\end{tabularx}
%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I add another line under Mobile: +55 555 555 555 it gets unaligned again :(

Comment: @Stefan, you are right. So I change solution and now should works with any number of lines in the second table column. See edited answer.